# How do I make a new column? For example if salary I want to categorize them into <$4000, $4000 to $6000, >$6000

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I make a new column? For example if salary I want to categorize them into <$4000, $4000 to $6000, >$6000
I have a dataframe that consists of various data including salary of the people and I would like to make a new column that would categorize them into certain salary groups as mentioned above.

I am using tidyverse packages only.

I was trying to use mutate but I wasn't sure how to divide them into groups

Comment: Look up the `case_when` function in dplyr, or use `cut` from base R.

Answer (score 3):

As @Jon Spring mentioned, you need to use `cut` (which is base R). Is something like this what you're after to add the column?

```
salary_groups <- c('£0-10', '£11-35', '£36-59', '£60-90')
your_df$new_column <- cut(your_df$salaries, c(1, 11, 36, 60, 91, 151, 251, 351, 751), include.highest=TRUE)
```

**EDITED IN LIGHT OF COMMENT**

In future, it's much easier to answer questions on this site if you include data sufficient for a minimally reproducible example.

Now, is this better for your purposes? I'm assuming your column listing existing salaries is headed `salaries`:

```
your_df %>%
  mutate(new_column = case_when(salaries > 6000 ~ '>$6000',
                             salaries > 4000 ~ '$4000-$6000',
                             TRUE ~ '<$4000' ))
```

[Here's the page on dplyr's `case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't really get the code 
My data consist of various number of salary for example, $3750 $3500 and I want to group them into <$4000 and any value from $4000 to $6000 into another group and above $6000 to another group and this category must be shown in a new column

Comment: I have over 200 rows of data for your information

Comment: @AiRobot I've edited my answer in light of your comments. Please mark my answer as correct/accepted if it answers your question, but feel free to follow-up if it does not. Thanks!